# Java - The method newDefaultUnpacker(byte[]) is undefined for the type MessagePack

Tags: java, msgpack

I'm trying to use the `newDefaultUnpacker` static method of the `MessagePack` class like this:

```
import org.msgpack.MessagePack;

Map<Value, Value> map = MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(myByteArray).unpackValue().asMapValue().map();
```

however I get the error:

```
The method newDefaultUnpacker(byte[]) is undefined for the type MessagePack
```

Initially I created the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>msgpack</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Changing it to this (or adding this in addition to the previous dependency) doesn't work.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
  <artifactId>msgpack-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.16</version>
</dependency>
```

What do I need to do to successfully reference `newDefaultUnpacker`? I don't get any hints that suggest a particular import that I should add, and `import org.msgpack.core` isn't recognised i.e. the package doesn't exist.

Comment: Sounds like the maven dependency is not updated in local m2 repo. The dependency in my pom is         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>msgpack-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.16</version>
  </dependency>
and importing the following classes work fine:
import org.msgpack.core.MessagePack;
import org.msgpack.value.Value;
I would suggest that you remove the old msgpack from your m2 repo manually and then perform Maven > Update project, with Force update of snapshot/releases in case you are using eclipse. I am sure other IDEs have similar functions.

Comment: Thanks @moonlighter. I believe I'm not using m2 - my understanding is that this is an Eclipse add-in? I resolved the issue by uninstalling and re-installing Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Maven (by removing the folder containing the bin and removing the folder from my Windows path under environment variables > system ). I then re-installed it the same way as I'd originally installed it, and everything worked.